# IIS 10 error when .html pages requested from browser(The specified CGI application encountered an error)

Tags: html, iis, cgi, config

IIS 10 error when .html pages requested from the browser(The specified CGI application encountered an error)

I am trying to rebuild a website on a new IIS 10 installation on Windows server 2019. (It is a site that runs well on a Windows2008R2 test box.) When I go in the browser and request index.html I get an error message "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process." When I rename the page to index.htm it works.

The error in the browser console says: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

But the pages character encoding is properly declared and works well on another server.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="PHP" path="*.html,*.php" verb="*" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="HTMLPHPMapping" path="*.html" verb="*" type="" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\php7\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="PHP74Mapping" path="*.php" verb="*" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\php7\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" type="" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
            <clear />
            <error statusCode="500" path="index.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="index.html" />
        </httpErrors>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 1) You don't need so many handlers for PHP. Just the first one should be enough. 2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Use FRT to learn more about the CGI error. You can edit the question to include important portion of FRT logs.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, I will do this and revert back. I was wondering why I can't see error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the handler correctly? We are always create module mapping for PHP cgi like 
this.

```
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="phpmaphtml" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3.9\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" />
        </handlers>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is working. Those mappings messed everything up.

Comment: @dupnic. I'm so glad my reply can help. It is so appericated if you could accept it as answer.